# A Select Array Not Showing Results

Tags: php, arrays, select

I am writing a CRON job that will execute daily.  First it will identify from a MySql table the date in a field 'FAPforSale_repost35'  If the date is the today date it will then execute commands to delete photo images in a directory, delete the directory, and finally remove the record from the database.

I am on step one which is to build the array of records that match the days date.  When I run the code, there are no errors but I am not getting results even though the records in the test table are set for today.  Below is the select

```
<?php

 define( "DIR", "../zabp_employee_benefits_processor_filesSm/", true );

 require( '../zipconfig.php' );
 require( DIR . 'lib/db.class.php' );
 require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_ZABP_merchants/configRecognition.php' );
 require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_ZABP_merchants/libRecognition/MailClass.inc' );



$todayRepost35 = date("Y-m-d");
echo $todayRepost35;



function repostEndSelect()

      {

        global $db;

    $this->db = $db;


     $data = $this->db->searchQuery( "SELECT `FAPforSale_IDnumber`,  `FAPforSale_image1`,  `FAPforSale_image2`,  `FAPforSale_image3`,  `FAPforSale_repost35`  FROM  `FAP_forSaleTest` Where `FAPforSale_repost35` = '$todayRepost35' ");


        $this->FAPforSale_IDnumber = $data[0]['FAPforSale_IDnumber'];
        $this->FAPforSale_image1 = $data[0]['FAPforSale_image1'];
        $this->FAPforSale_image2 = $data[0]['FAPforSale_image2'];
        $this->FAPforSale_image3 = $data[0]['FAPforSale_image3'];
        $this->FAPforSale_repost35 = $data[0]['FAPforSale_repost35'];

        echo $this->FAPforSale_IDnumber;
        echo $this->FAPforSale_image1;
        echo $this->FAPforSale_image2;
        echo $this->FAPforSale_image3;
        echo $this->FAPforSale_repost35;

    } // ends function...

echo( ' Finished...' );

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or direction.

Answer (score 0):

`$todayRepost35` is outside the scope of the function. You have to either scope it to the function, or pass it as an argument (the latter being the better idea):

```
function repostEndSelect() {
    global $db;
    global $todayRepost35;
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
function repostEndSelect($todayRepost35) {
    global $db;
    // ...
}
// ...
$test = repostEndSelect($todayRepost35);
```

Also, using `$this` inside a function will not work. If the function is part of a class, and you (for some reason) did not include the class definition, then ignore this.